# Python Pandas - Appending/updating key value pairs inside a dataframe with a dict column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key-value

Having this dataframe

```py
d = {'objects':[{'Sand':10},{'Seawater': 2, 'Crab': 30},{'Parasol': 50}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want this key-value pair

```py
{'Small': 1000}
```

to be inserted to every row that has at least a key-value pair with a value of less than 40.

```py
     objects
0    {'Sand': 10, 'Small': 1000}
1    {'Seawater': 2, 'Crab': 30, 'Small': 1000}
2    {'Parasol': 50}
```

I have tried looping over it but it yields 'None'.

```py
def your_small(x):
    if any(value < 40 for value in x.values()):
        return x.update({'Small': 1000})

d = {'objects':[{'Sand':10},{'Seawater': 2, 'Crab': 30},{'Parasol': 50}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['objects'] = df['objects'].map(your_small)
```

```
  objects
0    None
1    None
2    None
```

Comment: Before heading down this path, I would strongly suggest you rethink how you're using `pandas`, it's really not meant to store objects like `dict`s. If you use a `MultiIndex` this can be done efficiently and without much manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ALoll said, you might want to re-think your approach.

If you want to make your existing code work, you have to think about how map works: you must return a value in your map function. `x.update` returns `None`, and you have to return x as is if your conditions is not met:

```py
def your_small(x):
    if any(value < 40 for value in x.values()):
        return {**x, 'Small': 1000}
    return x
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try using MultiIndex as ALollz suggested. I just wanted this to work in the mean time.

Comment: @MasakiAndou If you truly do need to keep them as dicts for some other library or class then I wouldn't bother with the MultiIndex and stick with this good answer; you'll still pay the price of looping when you ultimately group and re-create the dicts in the end. I just mentioned it because if there's no need for the `dicts` then the correct use of pandas might be a MultiIndex, though you'd need to be careful as MultiIndices allow duplicate indices, while a dict will overwrite keys to ensure it's always unique.

Comment: @ALollz No, I just used dicts because they're more familiar to me in what I am doing. Going with what you said, I might have to make the keys as separate columns instead. That might be more efficient. Will it eat more memory though?

Answer (score 2):

If the dicts aren't really necessary here's a way with a MultiIndex. Here I'll assume the separate dicts have mostly non-overlapping keys so a long DataFrame seems more appropriate. (A wide DataFrame might be better if most dicts had overlapping keys)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(di, orient='index', columns=['N']) for di in d['objects']], 
               keys=range(len(d['objects'])))
#             N
#0 Sand      10
#1 Seawater   2
#  Crab      30
#2 Parasol   50

# Determine which original "rows" have at least one value < 40
s = df.N.lt(40).groupby(level=0).any()

df_add = pd.DataFrame({'N': 1000},
                      index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s[s].index, ['Small']]))

# Join them:
df = pd.concat([df, df_add]).sort_index()
#               N
#0 Sand        10
#  Small     1000
#1 Crab        30
#  Seawater     2
#  Small     1000
#2 Parasol     50
```

---

Here's a version with a wide DataFrame. Much easier to manipulate, but can get very large.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d['objects'])
#   Sand  Seawater  Crab  Parasol
#0  10.0       NaN   NaN      NaN
#1   NaN       2.0  30.0      NaN
#2   NaN       NaN   NaN     50.0

df.loc[df.lt(40).any(1), 'Small'] = 1000
#   Sand  Seawater  Crab  Parasol   Small
#0  10.0       NaN   NaN      NaN  1000.0
#1   NaN       2.0  30.0      NaN  1000.0
#2   NaN       NaN   NaN     50.0     NaN
```